# Python: create a sequence of dates with only weekdays (Monday to Friday)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date sequence

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
start = datetime(2018, 3, 4)
end = datetime(2018, 3, 17)
index1 = pd.date_range(start, end)
```

How can I extract only Monday to Friday from the sequence? Any other solution (not using datetime) will also be helpful.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the paremeter `freq` and set it to `B` for *business day frequency*

```
index1 = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='B')
```

Or you can use the dedicated method [`pandas.bdate_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html). You can find the other [frequencies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) :

```
index1 = pd.bdate_range(start, end)
```

Comment: Does the resulting sequence contain all Mondays to Fridays in the range, including holidays?

Comment: @user2644687 Why don't you try ? ;) It returns the same as your first method, but without Saturday and sunday, so yes only Mon->Fri ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `freq='B'` as parameter to `date_range` to avoid weekends (include only business days):

```
index1 = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='B')
```